# Customizing Jackson's deserialization depending on Jersey's request query param?

Tags: java, rest, serialization, jackson, jersey-2.0

I'm using Jackson 24.1 + Jersey 2.10 on my REST api.

In order to parse dates in a custom format, I have a Jackson deserializer like so:

```
public class JsonDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date>{

    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");

    @Override
    public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        gen.writeString(formattedDate);
    }

}
```

But I'd like to change how I deserialize dates depending on whether the user has included a given request header or not. To do that, I'd need to access Jersey's HttpRequestContext object inside Jackson's deserializer...

Is it possible to access Jersey's context within JAckson's serializers / deserializers when they are used together like this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't reach HttpRequest directly from the deserializer, however, I did something similar using a flag in my object.

```
    @XmlElement(name = "date")
    public String getDate() {
        return (formatFlag) ? dateFormatter1.format(date): dateFormatter2.format(date);
    }
```

then ofcourse formatFlag can be @XmlTransient

Comment: I really needed a global solution that would affect all entities. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

yep `ContextResolverFactory` does caching for context resolvers... I got this working in different way, Hope this helps -

Create XMLAdapter for Date as spring bean

```
import java.util.Date;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.time.DateFormatUtils;

@Named
public class RequestBasedXMLAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {
    @Inject
    private RequestData requestData;

    @Override
    public String marshal(Date value) throws Exception {

        return DateFormatUtils.format(value, requestData.getMyDateFormat());
    }

    @Override
    public Date unmarshal(String value) throws Exception {
        // i am not interested in incoming date
        return new Date();
    }
}
```

Create request scoped bean

```
import javax.inject.Named;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;

@Named
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class RequestData {
    private String myDateFormat;

    public String getMyDateFormat() {
        return myDateFormat;
    }

    public void setMyDateFormat(String myQueryParam) {
        this.myDateFormat = myQueryParam;
    }
}
```

Create context resolver for JAXBContext

1. Inject spring application context
2. Get your XMLAdapter defined as spring bean from context
3. return custom jaxbcontext (implemented as decorator) by modifying below methods

   ```
   public JAXBMarshaller createMarshaller() throws JAXBException {
       JAXBMarshaller marshaller = delegate.createMarshaller();
       marshaller.setAdapter(adapter);
       return marshaller;
   }

   public JAXBUnmarshaller createUnmarshaller() throws JAXBException {
       JAXBUnmarshaller unmarshaller = delegate.createUnmarshaller();
       unmarshaller.setAdapter(adapter);
       return unmarshaller;
   }
   ```

Now in your Resource class (where you have defined your GET/POST methods)

1. Inject request scoped bean RequestData
2. Set dateformat from query/header param in RequestData

Annotate your Date field in Response class as

```
 @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(RequestBasedXMLAdapter.class)
 private Date myCustomDate = new Date();
```

Now you should be able to change date format based on your request

*Also note I am using Moxy*

---

**OLD ANSWER**

I think you can do this by returning different ObjectMapper ...

Try

1. Write a ContextResolver for ObjectMapper
2. Inject HTTPHeader using @Context
3. Based on you header param return diff. mapper which uses appropriate date format

Drawback of above approach is that same date format will be applied to all the dates in that response.

Comment: That didn't work because the `ContextResolver`s are singleton, and won't ask for a new objectmapper on each request. It gets cached after the first requests.